# Rails and ajaxForm - how to detect exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ajax-forms

I made a standard Rails form and then wrapped it into JQ ajaxForm. Now the success callback is called in any case - whether an Rails exception occured while submitting or not.

How to make ajaxForm detect Rails exception? I want in case of error to remain in the form and display exception text.

**Additional references found:**

- [rails 3 - stay on page after ajax form submit but show "flash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418419/rails-3-stay-on-page-after-ajax-form-submit-but-show-flash)

Answer (score 1):

Check the request returned status to determine if there is an error or just do it like

```
 if(jqXHR === 0 ){
     //do something with error
 } else {
     //success
 }
```

**Edit:**
Try this

"A block of code to run if an error occurs"

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(res){
    $('body').prepend(res.responseText)
  }
});
```

For one method

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  rescue
    render 'shared/exception', :layout => 'overlay'
end
```

For the whole app

```
class ApplicationController
  around_filter :xhr_exceptions
  # ...
  private
  def xhr_exceptions
    yield
    rescue
      render('shared/exception', :layout => 'overlay', :status => 500) if request.xhr?
  end
end
```

http://codequietly.com/blog/2010/08/rails-ajax-and-exceptions-bring-it-on if its dead try cached

Comment: Still can't catch exception message in any way.